# Drop a floating <p> to bottom of a floating parent <div>

Tags: css, css-float

I have a `@page` media and a `<div>` element that floats to the top of the page; inside of that `<div>` are an `<img>` and a `<p>` (the image's caption) where the image floats left and the caption floats right within the parent:

```
<div style="float:top;">
    <img style="float:left;" ... />
    <p id="caption" style="float:right;">
    ...
    </p>
</div>
```

This places the image to the left side of the parent `<div>`, and right and at the top of the image is the caption.

Now it happens that the image can be rather tall with a short caption, in which case I would like the caption to still be at the right of the image, but at the *bottom of the parent `<div>`*. I can sort of "fake" this by giving the caption an actual `padding-top: ...pt` but that assumes I know the height of the image. (Which I don't because it's being scaled.)

How can I place the caption at the bottom-right of the parent `<div>` for unknown image heights?

Comment: make it `position:absolute` and `bottom:0; right:0`? But that'll give you overlapping problems if things shrink down far enough, since it'll be removed from the normal document flow.

Comment: Marc B: naw, I can't have things break out of the flow :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use absolute position:

```
div{ /*replace it with your div id*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;/*to overcome from the overlap*/
}
#caption{/*caption you want to get at bottom is now relative to div*/
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the parent `<div>` actually does float to the top (I fixed the question). In that context, can I combine the float with the position?